# Insert values if records don't already exist in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to get this working, but Postgres doesn't like having the `WHERE` clause in this type of insert.

```
  INSERT INTO keys(name, value) VALUES
    ('blah', 'true')
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM keys WHERE name='blah'
  );
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In Postgres, there is a really nice way to do that:

```
INSERT INTO keys(name, value) 
    SELECT 'blah', 'true'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM keys WHERE name='blah'
);
```

hope that helps.-

Comment: It beats me why suddenly we do not use VALUES here.... I've looked at so many places to find where people are using VALUES, but it seems "SELECT" is used instead. Super confusing?

Comment: @PascalvKooten because we need the ``WHERE`` to make our selection of values invalid if we can't find the key.

Comment: @PascalVKooten The indentation might have been throwing you off: the `WHERE` clause belongs to the `SELECT` part of the statement, rather than the overall `INSERT`.

Answer (score 31):

In Postgresql 9.5 you can now use `on conflict do nothing` if you also have a unique key or constraint:

```
insert into KEYS (name, value) values (
'blah', 'true') on conflict (name) do nothing;
```

Comment: how is that different than `insert into where not exists...` ? More safe when used concurrently?

Comment: @Konrad as far as I know, the `on conflict` clause only works on unique keys and constraints. for "normal columns", you should use the "where not exists". From the INSERT documentation on postgres: `Specifies which conflicts ON CONFLICT takes the alternative action on by choosing arbiter indexes. Either performs unique index inference, or names a constraint explicitly`