# How to use pandas.to_sql but only add row if row doesn't exist yet

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I have some experience with python but very new to the SQL thing and trying to use pandas.to_sql to add table data into my database, but when I add I want it to **check if the data exists before append**

This are my 2 dataframes

```
>>> df0.to_markdown()
|    |   Col1 |   Col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      0 |     00 |
|  1 |      1 |     11 |

>>> df1.to_markdown()
|    |   Col1 |   Col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      0 |     00 |
|  1 |      1 |     11 |
|  2 |      2 |     22 |
```

So here I use the pandas to_sql

```
>>> df0.to_sql(con=con, name='test_db', if_exists='append', index=False)
>>> df1.to_sql(con=con, name='test_db', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Here I check my data inside the database file

```
>>> df_out = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM test_db""", con)
>>> df_out.to_markdown()
|    |   Col1 |   Col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      0 |      0 |
|  1 |      1 |     11 |
|  2 |      0 |      0 | # Duplicate
|  3 |      1 |     11 | # Duplicate
|  4 |      2 |     22 |
```

But I want my database to look like this, so **I don't want to add the duplicate data to my database**

```
|    |   Col1 |   Col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      0 |      0 |
|  1 |      1 |     11 |
|  3 |      2 |     22 |
```

Is there any option I can set or some line of code to add to make this happend?

Thankyou!

edit: There are some SQL code to only pull unique data, but what I want to do is don't add the data to the database in the first place

Comment: There is no option to do it with pandas.to_sql. You should use insted **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...**

Comment: Have you checked this link - [Postgres: INSERT if does not exist already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069718/postgres-insert-if-does-not-exist-already)

Comment: Reply Comment#2
Yes, but that includes SQL code, I'm looking vanilla pandas code :))

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous you do know that you are writing a SQL query string to the `pd.to_sql`

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan No I don't, but I'm trying to make a function on top of `pd.to_sql` so I can blindly throw in bunch of data without need of checking, and let the function check for me instead :)

Answer (score 7):

Don't use to_sql a simple query can work

```
query = text(f""" INSERT INTO test_db VALUES {','.join([str(i) for i in list(df0.to_records(index=False))])} ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_db_pkey DO NOTHING""")

self.engine.connect().execute(query)
```

For each DataFrame change df0 to df1

Follow these link for a better understanding

- [Insert values if records don't already exist in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918449/insert-values-if-records-dont-already-exist-in-postgres)
- [How to upsert pandas DataFrame to PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366664/how-to-upsert-pandas-dataframe-to-postgresql-table)

Comment: This method doesn't work with <NA> (eg. null boolean) or nan (eg. null string) values

Answer (score 0):

For example in my Sqlite 3 database I used temporary table:

I inserted all the dataframe data into temporary table:

> df0.to_sql(con=con, name='temptable', if_exists='append', index=False)
>
> df1.to_sql(con=con, name='temptable', if_exists='append', index=False)

Then I copy only new data and drop (delete) the table:

```
con.executescript('''
INSERT INTO test_db
SELECT test_db.* FROM temptable 
LEFT JOIN test_db on 
   test_db.Col1 = temptable.Col1
WHERE test_db.Col1 IS NULL; -- only items, that not presented in 'test_db' table

DROP TABLE temptable;
''')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. if the data from database is not big, read the data from database into the dataframe, and combine the two columns (Col1 and Col2) to create a new column, i.e. combined_column, and save this into a list combined_column_list.  Filter out those rows from df0 and df2, whose corresponding combined_column does not appear in the combined_column_list, and inserted the filtered rows directly to the database table.
2. Insert df1 and df2 to a temporary table, e.g. with name "temp". Using python  pymysql to run the following code:

   ```
   conn = pymysql.connect(host=DB_ip, user=DB_user,passwd=DB_password,db=DB_name)    
   cur = conn.cursor()

   temp_query =" insert into  test_db (select * from temp where ( `Col1`, `Col2`) not in (select `Col1`, `Col2` from test_db ));"
   cur.execute(temp_query)
   conn.commit()
   ```

This will only insert the new data to the database table.

Answer (score -2):

add this code to your function

```
remove_duplicate = 'EXEC remove_duplicate'
cursor.execute(remove_duplicate)
cursor.commit()
```

and create procedure in your db:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE remove_duplicate AS
BEGIN
;WITH duplicates as (SELECT col1, col2,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, ORDER BY col1) AS number_of_duplicates
    FROM dbo.table)
    DELETE FROM duplicates WHERE number_of_duplicates > 1

END
go
```